# Retrieve all pickled data in a folder

Tags: python, pickle

I'm new to Python.

I have matrices saved in a specific folder as `.pkl`.
I would like to retrieve pickled data with a for loop over this folder.
I also would like the new variable to have the same name as the file from which I'm reading the data.

In the end, what I want is to generalize the operation below for all data in the folder `Output`

```
with open('../Output/MatrixA.pkl', 'rb') as fin:
     MatrixA = pickle.load(fin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `sys.modules` and `setattr` will work like charm:

```
import pickle
from sys import modules
from os import listdir

main_script = modules['__main__']

for file in [path for path in listdir() if path.endswith('pk1')]:
    with open(file, "rb") as fp:
        setattr(main_script, fp.name.split('.')[0], pickle.load(fp))


print(a, b, c, d, e, sep='\n')
```

code used to generate sample files - a~e.pk1:

```
import pickle

for i, n in enumerate('abcde'):
    with open(f"{n}.pk1", "wb") as fp:
        pickle.dump([*iter(range(i))], fp)
```

output:

```
[]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

But would be nice if you convert those `pickles` to `json` as *pickled file* are ***dependent*** to python versions, and are potential threat.

Use this to convert all `.pk1` in directory:

```
import json
import pickle
from os import listdir


for file in [path for path in listdir() if path.endswith('pk1')]:
    with open(file, "rb") as fp:
        with open(file.split('.')[0] + ".json", "wt") as fp_json:
            json.dump(pickle.load(fp), fp_json)
```